# Setting up a SRV record to redirect from subdomain to main domain but different port

Tags: networking, dns, srv

So this is my desired result.

I have a VPS (hosted at DigitalOcean) that has two servers running. One is a webserver listening on port 80 that can be accessed simply by typing my domain name like `myfirefly.me`

The other server is also a webserver but listening on port 8442. It can be accessed like `myfirefly.me:8442`.

What I want is to be able to access it like `elopakao.myfirefly.me`.

If I understood my google results correctly, the easiest way to do this is using SRV records. DigitalOcean provides support for them but I'm having trouble understanding what I need to type in each of the fields. This is my current setup:

`_sip._tcp.myfirefly.me.    IN SRV  0 5 8442 elopakao.myfirefly.me.`

where `myfirefly.me` is my domain and `elopakao` is the desired subdomain.
Apparently the setting has propagated but when I type in `elopakao.myfirefly.me` I don't get anything.

What I'm assuming is happening is that `elopakao.myfirefly.me` is being routed to `elopakao.myfirefly.me:8442` instead of `myfirefly.me:8442`

How can I make this work?

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue right now, did you ever manage to get this resolved?

Comment: @hhanesand If I remember correctly I think SRV is not the way to go. It's not that well supported. I think that browsers also need to support it to make it work, and they don't.

Comment: Yeah, I have been realizing that over the last few hours of investigation. Thanks anyways!